# Recieved [Error data].. Socket programming in python

Tags: python

I amusing a client to send a message to a python server.

client side: client.send("1")
Server side:

```
 d=clientsocket.recv(1024)
 if (d=="1"):
    print(" Correct value")
```

It won't print correct value. I know the error at recv as I don't know how it works. Could anyone please help me to solve this matter.

Comment: What value has *d* afterwards?

Comment: Ironically when I printed d, the value on screen was 1. I am confused actually>>>>

Comment: Most likely, client and server have different ideas of representing the digit. Unicode, UTF8, ASCII ... Note that in Python 2.x default is extended ASCII, where in 3.x it is unicode. There also exist padding with non-printable zero-bytes....

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I have read it but  I still can't solve it.  Any suggestion? what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need simple modification to work it correctly:-

in client correct like below:-

```
client.send("1".encode())
```

in server correct like below:-

```
d=clientsocket.recv(1024).decode()
if (d=="1"):
    print(" Correct value")
```

I have created one client and server for you which is working fine in Python 3.4. Please try and check:

Here is your server

```
import socket
import sys

HOST = "localhost"
PORT = 8000

print("Creating socket...")
sc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print("Binding socket...")
try:
    sc.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as err:
    print("Error binding socket, {}, {}".format(err[0], err[1]))
print("bound Successful")

# Configure below how many client you want that server can listen to simultaneously
sc.listen(2)
print("Server is listening on {}:{}".format(HOST, PORT))
while True:
conn, addr = sc.accept()
print("Connection from: " + str(addr))
print("Receiving data from client\n")
data = conn.recv(1024).decode()
print("Client says :" + data)
if(data == "2"):
    print(" Ooh you are killing me with value :" + data)
    conn.sendall(str.encode("\n I am server and you killed me with :" + data))
    break;
elif(data == "1"):
    print(" Correct value :" + data)
    conn.sendall(str.encode("\n I am server and you hit me with correct value:" + data))
else:
    print(" You are sending a wrong value :" + data)
    conn.sendall(str.encode("\n I am server and you hit me with wrong value :" + data))
sc.close()
```

and now your client is here:-

```
import socket
import sys

HOST = "localhost"
PORT = 8000
print("creating socket")
sc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print("Connecting to host")
try:
    sc.connect((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as err:
    print("Error: could not connect to host, {}, {}".format(err[0], err[1]))
    sys.exit()
print("Connection established to host")
message = "1" # Run client 3 times with value message = '1' and '5' and '2'
sc.send(message.encode())
data = sc.recv(1024).decode()
print("Server response is : " + data)
sc.close()
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I have tried your suggestion and the result it's still the same. It won't print " correct value".

Comment: It should work. you might have some other issue. Just print the value of 'd' and check.

Comment: @Hayder, I am adding one server and client program here which is running as per your expectation. Hope this will help. Please let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: I am so thankful. It works like a charm and I am so happy for this. Kudos.